# Scheduler Design with Slots

Tags: website-design, usability, forms, gui-design, layout

I am trying to create a UI design for recurring events.

Example:

> John, cuts hair on week days monday-friday, from 02 Feb 2014 to 04
>   Apr 2014, only between 10 A.M to 1 P.M. Also he will do it for `45 mins`
>   each time slot

Referenced this screenshot from [Schedular .Net UI DESIGN](http://scheduler-net.com/demo_recurring.aspx)

[image]

How can we specify 45 minute time slots in this design? Could some one help me to reorganize this UI/UX?

Comment: Although I can understand what you mean it might help you get more answers if you can clarify your question

Comment: @tim.baker, i want to mix the slot also in the design

Comment: So what you're saying is events need to recur a set number of times within a single day (e.g. every 45 minutes within a given time range) as well as that pattern recurring over a longer period (e.g. from 02 Feb to 04 April)?

Comment: @MattObee, you are correct. Exactly the same

Comment: I would recommend at looking at how Outlook has handled this functionality. They seem to have all bases covered.

Answer (score 1):

Your UI only allows for repeating events by days. You need to add the ability to repeat within one day.

Perhaps something like this:

Default state:

```
Repeat:  ( ) Daily    
         ( ) Weekly
         ( ) Monthly
         ( ) Yearly
         -----------------------------------
         [ ] Multiple times during the day
```

You can still choose to repeat the event the standard ways (radio buttons) but, *in addition*, you can set it up to repeat multiple times on each of those particular days. If the user then checks the last option, you could add to the interface an option to choose the interval and number of times:

```
Repeat:  ( ) Daily    
         ( ) Weekly
         ( ) Monthly
         ( ) Yearly
         -----------------------------------
         [X] Multiple times during the day
             Every [ 45 minutes  \/ ]
             a total of [ 4 \/ ] times
```

Before doing any of this, however, do check that this is't just an edge case for very few users. I can't imagine too many situations where people need to put on their calendar multiple *exact duplicate* events in one day.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd be tempted to use a simple checkbox + edit field along the lines of

[] Split into subtasks of [x] minutes

where the value of x is editable up to the duration of the event. This could be under the "Time Period" section or possibly in its own "Subtasks" section

On OK this would create the required number of consecutive events in the specified time scale. The default name of each event would be the description with Slot 1, 2, 3, 4 appended, eg Haircut (Slot 1). This could then be changed afterwards if necessary.

You would of course need to validate the value of x and show how many repeats were going to be created. You would also need to report/handle if the overall event duration isnt an exact multiple of the subtask.
You should also allow specifying a *number* of subtasks (eg 4) rather than a *duration* of subtasks (eg 45 mins)

If this was a rare use case you may want to consider hiding it under a button so as not to confuse the majority of your users.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd set your persons schedule to maybe start at the start of every hour (or however you'd like to do so)

So have a drop down (or radio set) that has:
10-10:45
11-11:45
12-12:45

Then maybe a dropdown for recurrence:
Weekly
Bi-Weekly
Monthly

Comment: Welcome to UX StackExchange @Chris. Can you provide evidence to back up your answer, such as a site that has a similar UI pattern, or an article with recommendations on how to do this? (Generally speaking, I tend to avoid drop-downs because they are clunky for users with limited mobility.)